# mousemove event jquery - need assistance

Tags: jquery

I am completely a beginner in jquery, my question is simple:

I have two elements, the `mousemove` event is on `div1` and I'm moving `div2` according to the  mouse's position, so I am facing two problems.

1. when i am hovering `div2`, the mousemove event stops but I want it to continue as long as my cursor is over `div1` and also when I move cursor to the right, the div doesn't move properly
2. I want the `div2` to be in middle of cursor, I tried taking `div1` offset left, top etc, but still no luck

any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Illum/pPn3v/

Answer (score 1):

Its works here :

1 :

```
<div id="box1">
  <div id="box2"></div>
</div>
```

2 :

```
$("#box2").css("left", e.pageX - 50);
$("#box2").css("top", e.pageY + -50);
```

`e.pageX` and `e.pageY` are pixel measurements of how far from the left and top of the web page (respectively) the mouse pointer is.

Without the 50 pixel offsets, the code tells the browser to align the top left hand corner of the element to the mouse cursor. Any modifiers to the pixel values at this point will be **relative to this position**.

Because the box is 100 x 100, we can work out that the center point is at X:50, Y:50. From there, to align the box's center to the mouse pointer, all we need to do is shift the box's position 50 pixels towards the top and left. In this case, you're subtracting that amount from the current position values (because you're moving 'backwards').

JsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/pPn3v/135/

Hope that helps

Comment: It does work, but could you explain what is '-50' and + '-50' and why did you add it?

Comment: because your div#box2 has width 100px and height 100px